# Renaming links from top menu using local.xml?

Tags: magento

In the default checkout.xml there is:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCartLink"></action>
        <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Eg: I want to rename My Cart, My Cart(1) to Current order, Current order(1) respectively.

Comment: Do you want to rename the links? Or change where they point to?

Answer (score 2):

You can find your translation files here "/app/locale/YOUR_LANGUAGE". To change the top links menu, you have to open "mage_checkout.csv".

Comment: You shouldn't modify core files. Instead create/edit the files in your theme.